# How to add an Entry to a gtk.ComboBox

Tags: python, combobox, pygtk

I'm trying to add an Entry field to a gtk.ComboBox. The easy way out would be to use gtk.ComboBoxEntry, but I read [somewhere](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2011-January/msg09929.html) that ComboBoxEntry is deprecated.

I tried setting the property "has-entry" to True, but this can only be done on construction.

Then I tried, somewhat desperately, to add this as a keyword parameter to the constructor, but 'has_entry' doesn't seem to be an existing keyword parameter.

So, how do I set a property at construction time in Python?

Comment: [gtk.combo_box_text_new_with_entry()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkcomboboxtext.html#function-gtk--combo-box-text-new-with-entry) ?

Comment: Thanks, SiHa... Yes, I did find that out. I didn't know the gtk functions were available by their original names in Python, till I did a dir(gtk). Also, it seems that in some installations gtk.ComboBox(has_entry = True) works, but it wasn't accepted here (a friendly help from IRC told me it _did_ work for him - go figure).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help on the #gtk+ IRC channel, I found out that (at least some) of the pygtk functions are available by their C-names in Python. So, it is possible to write:

```
cbboxe = gtk.combo_box_new_with_entry() or
cbboxe = gtk.combo_box_text_new_with entry()
```

Strangely enough, it was also indicated that

```
gtk.ComboBox(has_entry = True)
```

should work. @ebassi (IRC) showed me it worked - I tried it here but wasn't able to get it accepted. Same PyGTK version and all. YMMV :)

(Thanks @SiHa for reminding me I had this question still open!)